# android - custom list view with one image at top

Tags: android, image, listview, android-edittext

I have own custom list view, which has in one row TextView with EditText. Now I want to have one image above this list view which change image according to selected EditText in list view. So for example when user clicks on EditText in second row, the top image above the list view will change to img2. When user clisks on EditText in first row, it will be img1 and so on.

I have problem that I don't know how can I find out which EditText was selected in ListView.

Thanks

Comment: you can get the id by the position of the edit field or the text on the field or the id of the button

Answer (score 1):

You could change your layout like this:

```
<LinearLayout orientation="vertical">
   <ImageView/>
   <ListView/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in your java code, you can pass this `ImageView` as a parameter to your `Adapter` constructor. In the `getView` method, you could set a click listener to the `EditText` and based on that you could change the image in the `ImageView`.

Comment: but how can I get position of which edit text was clicked. Because onClick is called but in that method I don't know which edit text was clicked. Because I have a lot of images but they are different for all edit texts.

Answer (score 0):

Your layout should be like below.

Demo.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_demo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_demo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Demo.java

```
public class Demo extends Activity {

    ArrayList<String> textViewList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> imageList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> editTextList = new ArrayList<String>();

    ListView list;
    ImageView ivDemo;

    ListDemoAdapter adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_demo);
        ivDemo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv_demo);    

        adapter = new ListDemoAdapter(this, textViewList, editTextList, imageList);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Picasso.with(this).load(imageList.get(i)).into(ivDemo);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

here you get the position of row which is clicked by user for edit text. using this position you can easily load image from that position in Arraylist and display it in Imageview which is above ListView.

Comment: Yes, this is one possible solution. But I tried it and onItemClick is not called when I hit edit box, only when I hit row in listview.

Answer (score 0):

You can add as many headers as you like by calling addHeaderView() multiple times. You have to do it before setting the adapter to the list view.

you can do this like this

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_mage_layout, yourlistview, false);
yourlistview.addHeaderView(header, null, false);
```

and remember during onItemclick the position becomes

```
position=position-1
```

otherwise you gonna get error during onItem click since one of the row of listview is occupied by your custom header